# Program terminates in initialization of large array

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have V = 3997962, and I want to have an array of that size consisting of vectors of ints in C++.

When I initialize it like this:

```
const int V = 3997962;

vector<int> array[V];
```

The program terminates without prompting to any error.

Is it stack overflow error? How can I go about this?

Should I define it like this:

```
vector<int>* test = new vector<int>[V];
```

How can I pass this variable to a function? And how it should be defined as an argument? Do I need to delete it after all?

Comment: You won't get a stack overflow from using std::vector because it allocates the data on the heap. You could get bad_alloc if the allocation is too big though.

Comment: You need to use `()` not `[]`.

Comment: @Borgleader it actually is a stack overflow, due to too many vectors on the stack

Comment: @sjdowling Then it would not be an array of vectors.

Comment: @JosephMansfield I see, it wasn't clear from his original example what he meant.

Comment: @sjdowling What's the difference? How I can provide it to a function?

Comment: @tux3 Yes but it's not the use of vector that causes it. It's the use of an array ;)

Comment: @SergeyIvanov sjdowling misinterpreted your question. If you changed the `[]` to `()`, you would just have a single vector of `V` `int`s. However, you appear to want an array of `V` vectors of `int`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is a local variable, you are basically asking for almost 8 million pointer variables in automatic storage. This will likely fail due to stack overflow.

You can instead use a vector of vectors.

```
vector<vector<int>> array(V);
```

The above results in a vector called `array` that is populated with `V` default initialized `vector<int>`s.

Comment: And what should I do if I want to push back to some element of that array? Say, can I do array[3].push_back(0) immediately after initialization? Or I have to fill in the first 3 elements of array first, and then push to the fourth?

Comment: You can push back immediately.

Comment: The first vector is immediately populated with V empty but valid vectors, awaiting your orders.

Answer (score 6):

It is very likely a stack overflow.

You are allocating `V` `vector<int>`s. While the elements of those vectors will be allocated on the heap, the vectors themselves (which contain a pointer and a few other objects) are being allocated on the stack. If you have `V` of these, you will likely hit your stack limit.

```
vector<int>* test = new vector<int>[V];
```

This is one possible solution, but not ideal. It will require you to `delete[]` the array later, with `delete[] test;`. You *could* get around this problem by wrapping this dynamically allocated array in a smarter pointer, but keep reading for a better solution.

How you would pass this to other functions is not really relevant (you should design function parameters completely independent of how the client might allocate them), but you could just pass the pointer around:

```
void f(vector<int>* param);
f(test);
```

The parameter could alternatively be written as `vector<int> param[]`, which might better express that this pointer points to an array. `const`s could also be added where you want immutability. However, we can find a nicer solution by avoiding using `new` and raw pointers entirely.

Instead, I would recommend having a `vector<vector<int>>`:

```
vector<vector<int>> test(V);
```

Now you only actually have one `vector` on the stack. The elements of that `vector`, which are themselves `vector`s, will be allocated on the heap, and their elements also.

Comment: Why not just make a `unique_ptr<vector<int>[]>` instead of a raw pointer that you'd have to `delete[]` ?

Comment: @tux3 You could, but I felt like stepping in that direction would mislead the asker.

Comment: @Joseph Could you demystify this amusing phrase by showing a code: " but you could either pass the pointer around or dereference the pointer and pass it by reference."

Comment: Still, it might be worth a side-note. We have to get people off this `new`/`delete` crap somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You should provide that the array would have static storage duration.
Either define it outside any function in some name space or use keyword static if you want to define it in a function (for example main)

```
static std::vector<int> array[V];
```

because the stack memory is very limited.

Otherwise define it in the heap or use the same vector. For example

```
std::vector<vector<int>> array( V );
```

Or

```
std::vector<vector<int>> array;
array.reserve( V );
```

Take into account that class `std::vector` has member function `max_size` that allows to obtain information about the maximum acceptable size of the vector.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest making it static without explaining the draw-backs.

Comment: "the heap" :( Aren't we past this yet?

Comment: @Neil Kirk  I think that it is only you who has thought that they are equivalent.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Behave yourself. He does _not_ think that they are equivalent: in fact he _just_ pointed out that they are not. He is saying that less knowledgeable people may misread your answer as suggesting that _you_ think they are equivalent, and he's right.

Comment: Clearly OP is novice about vectors so using reserve instead of resize is very tricky in my opinion.

Comment: BTW, out of interest, are you still allowed to drive? :-)

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit Does he pay your job of prompter?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: It's a valuable service that I provide for free.

Answer (score 1):

While the vector data is located on the heap. The vector object size itself is (on a 64bit, Linux) 24 bytes, so you are locating 24*3997962 ~ 95MB on the stack. The default stack limit on a linux machine for example is ~8MB (try `ulimit -a` to check). So it is likely a stack over flow.

Comment: On my 64-bit OS, I can get 16 or 32 byte vectors depending on my compiler settings.

Comment: @NeilKirk Sure, the actual size may vary depending on the settings. Edit the answer if you feel like it.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for `3997962 * sizeof(std::vector<int>)` in automatic storage space if this is declared local to some function. To better understand how much space the basic management members of a `std::vector<int>` occupy, consider:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(std::vector<int>) << '\n';
}
```

**Output** (OSX 10.10, 64bit clang 3.5)

```
24
```

thusly, (at least on my platform) you're requesting *at least* 3997962 * 24, or **95951088** bytes ( roughly **92 MB**) of automatic storage. So yes, you're very likely blowing out your automatic storage space. To place all but the primary management data of a single vector on the heap, you can:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv(N);
```

which will create a vector of `N` vectors of `int`, all of which are initially empty and heap-managed. the core management data internal to the base vector `vv` is still in automatic storage, but as you can see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(std::vector<std::vector<int>>) << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
24
```

the footprint in automatic storage is *considerably* reduced

To address your followup questions of:

- How can I pass this variable to a function?
- How it should be defined as an argument?

How to pass this (the first question) depends entirely on whether you need to modify its content, and will effect how you declare the parameter (the second question). To avoid expensive copies, pass it by reference. Second, if the callee doesn't need to modify the data, pass it as `const`:

```
// read-only, pass as const-reference
void doesnt_modify(const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vv)
{
    // use here, can't modify
}

// writable, pass as reference
void can_modify(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vv)
{
    // use here, can modify
}
```